# How do I use chmod to change permissions?

Tags: readonly, chmod

I want to enable Remote Connections to MySQL on 1&1
i followed their explanation

https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/administration-c37694/enable-remote-connections-to-mysql-a781586.html

but the  file system is Read-only.

with  ls -l ==>

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Nov  8 16:43 mysql
```

inside this folder mysql i have this file

```
-rw-r--r-- 105 root root 3533 Oct 22  2015 my.cnf
```

with ls -alt

```
***drwxr-xr-x  88 root root 4096 Nov  8 16:52 ..

drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Nov  8 16:43 .

-rw-r--r-- 105 root root 3533 Oct 22  2015 my.cnf***
```

I want to modify this file with chmod
but i have this error 
**chmod: changing permissions of 'my.cnf': Read-only file system**

How to make a my.cnf writable? and after modification make it readable
Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable

Comment: Should the file-system in question be read-only?

Answer (score 1):

If a filesystem has been mounted read-only, chmod will not work since it's a write operation too.

> sudo mount -o remount,rw '/mnt/yourmounthere'

If the device has a write lock on it (like SD memory cards), you need to turn it off. Hardware locks cannot be disabled by software. Note that the write lock on SD memory cards is located from the sight you see the letters near the up left corner and it looks like a very small switch.

Comment: could you clarify your general setup? What System are you using on what Hardware? Please update your initial Question so people can understand it more easily.

Answer (score -2):

"sudo chmod 777 my.cnf" for change like root user

Comment: OP's device is mounted for read-only; check the error message!

Comment: If  filesystem  is read only  why he  gives this solution
https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/webspace-and-access-c85098/ssh-c37775/change-file-permissions-via-ssh-a606252.html